# remove or find NaN in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `x2` as

```
> x2
    x2
 1 NaN
 2 0.1
 3 NaN
 4 0.2
 5 0.3
```

I would like to remove the `NaN` from this column. Is there a quick way to do that?

Comment: `is.nan` is specific for `NaN`. Current answers will also deal with other missing values.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
x2 <- na.omit(x2)
```

may work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Simply this

```
x2 = x2[!is.na(x2)];
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `subset` could be useful for using complex indicators.

```
subset(x2, !is.nan(x2[[1]]))
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution could be:

```
x2 <- c(NaN, 0.1, NaN, 0.2, 0.3)

library(hablar)

s(x2)
```

which gives you:

```
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.3
```